How to add a different layout (CSS, javascript) to a razor page in Blazor WASM?
I am working on a Blazor WASM e-commerce application using the .NET 6 old version with a default template. I want to add a new razor page with a different look while keeping the old ones in the project. How can I achieve this?
Specifically, I want to add a new page with custom CSS and JavaScript, without affecting the existing pages. Can you guide me on how to do this step by step?
What I have done so far is, create an empty SampleLayout and add it under Shared folder beside the MainLayout.
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

I created a Test folder under Pages and added _Imports.razor having this inside of it.
@layout SampleLayout

Then added Home.razor page inside of the Test folder. Having page directive (@page "/Test/Home") and some markup with bootstrap. When I start the application and navigate to /Test/Home there is nothing displayed and no error as well.
I also added the required CSS and JavaScript files under wwwroot-css and -js folders. But I am not sure where to call them in the Home.razorpage.
Edit 1)
Adding @Body to this new layout makes the page display. But still, I need to somehow add the related JS and CSS to this new Home.razor page.
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/img/apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/templatemo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">

    <!-- Load fonts style after rendering the layout styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;200;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fontawesome.min.css">

</head>
...

 <!-- Start Script -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/templatemo.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- End Script -->


You are correct. Add @layout SampleLayout to the "test" folder's _Imports.razor to make it effect on all pages within this folder.
For the css/script reference, you could simply put them in the "Home.razor" or "SampleLayout.razor" to make it effect on pages within this folder.
Besides, you could also set the layout dynamically by modify the App.razor like following
@inject NavigationManager manager
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="GetLayoutType()" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code{
    private Type GetLayoutType()
    {
        var relativePath = manager.ToBaseRelativePath(manager.Uri);

        if (relativePath.StartsWith("Home"))
        {
            return typeof(SampleLayout);
        }
        else
        {
            return  typeof(MainLayout);
        }
    }   
}

-----------------------update---------------------
The way you apply css and scripts only to this page:
@page "/Test/Home"
@layout SampleLayout
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    This is a new look page.
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>


How to put CSS and JS into SampleLayout.razor? Just by adding script and link files?

Where to put those JS and CSS files? I tried in the index.html but didn't work for JS.

@raysefo I mean you could put <link...><script src-..> in the SampleLayout.razor or Home.razor.  index.html also works. But the Browser may cache the old index.html so it doesn't work. You could try "ctrl+f5" to reload the script.

I wonder if there is a way to only apply specific CSS files for a specific razor page? If so how? Let's say I just want bootstrap and custom CSS files for Home.razor.

@raysefo But just put the reference at the bottom of home.razor will be only applied to this page. I update the pattern in answer. To be honest, I am a bit confused about your question.
